# Input goes in an infinite loop in a C program

Tags: c

I have a C Code snippet below for the question http://www.codechef.com/ACMKAN13/problems/LINEPROB , but the input seems to go in an infinite loop, it is not stopping. Can someone please take a look.

Thanks in advance :)

The entire code is at: http://pastebin.com/aKdybQtm

```
int main(){
    int *res, in[4], i, j, n;
    j = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    res = malloc(n*(sizeof(int)));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &in[0]);
        scanf("%d", &in[1]);
        scanf("%d", &in[2]);
        scanf("%d", &in[3]);
        res[j] = countbox(in);
        j++;
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d\n", res[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you tell the input goes into an infinite loop? Maybe `countbox` (which isn't defined here) is slow or doesn't terminate?

Comment: I added a printf to check that in countbox function

Comment: The problem is somewhere in `countbox`. Check the `while` conditions you have there. Also, I'm not sure if you are aware that when you divide integers in C, it doesn't automatically give you a floating point answer. It will do integer arithmetic. That could impact your computations.

Comment: But, to check that I added printf("here") just at the start of countbox function. It does not print that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem in your `for` loop in `main`. Problem is in loop in your `countbox` function

```
if(x1 < x2){
    while((x1+i)<x2){
        if(getY(m, (x1+i), in) != (x1+i))
            count++;
    }
}
```

Once `(x1+i)<x2` condition becomes true it will always be true because you are not updating `i`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the problem. But when I put a printf at the start of the function, why doesn't it gets printed?

Comment: It is printing on my compiler the word `here`.

Comment: @user1675947, about the printf: My guess is that you don't have a newline at the end of the string you print, and since stdout is line buffered, it doesn't show up on the screen.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy; I think you are right. I read about it somewhere.